# How much is ble Tx power of RPI zero WH

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero-w

I'm planning to estimate distances between some RPI ZERO WH using bluetooth.

I'd like to know Tx power of BLE of RPI ZERO WH to measure distance.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would measure the value yourself at 1m and use that value in a beacon transmission. Using the RSSI graph on [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) can be a good starting place.

Although using the TX power alone is a challenging way to get an accurate location. There are plenty of research articles and blogs about the challenge. Searching "Bluetooth Real Time Location Systems (RTLS)" or "Bluetooth RSSI stability" should give you plenty of results.
For example: https://www.beaconzone.co.uk/blog/category/rssistability/